# Fetch All keys from params in script painless query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using painless script query in elasticsearch and I want to fetch all the keys inside params. So I want to access it like params[0] key.
Something like-

```
{"script":
    {"inline":"for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.entities.length; ++i) 
        {if(ctx._source.entities[i].id == '4b55dc24e73afd71ae8d37ee70eae2e4')
            {for(int j=0;j<params.length;++j){ctx._source.entities[i].params[j].key = params[j].value;}
             }","lang":"painless","params" : {"nonProfit"  : false,"entityType":'Entity'}}}
```

But can't find the proper syntax. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you join your mappings?

Comment: Here Joining Mapping makes no sense as params have been sent at the time of query. I just want all the params as Key Value. But not able to do that. Just check the inline script in elasticsearch , I am talking in that context.